# Error encountered using decorator to update wrapper

Tags: python, decorator, attributeerror, functools

I've encountered a rather cryptic (to me at least) error message while trying to use a decorator to update a function's wrapper.  Any ideas how I could remedy this?

I've tried to make my code as general as possible so it will apply to other situations as well.

```
def decorator(d):
    """Make function d a decorator: d wraps a function fn."""

    def _d(fn):
        return functools.update_wrapper(d(fn), fn)
    functools.update_wrapper(_d, d)
    return _d


@decorator
def f(fn):
    """Converts the string fn to a function and returns it.
    Because of the @decorator decorator, _f.__name__ should
    be identical to f.__name__"""

    f.__name__ = fn
    def _f(fn):
        return eval(fn)
    return _f

g = f('x**2')
print g.__name__
```

Desired output:

```
>>>x**2
```

Actual output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\swampy-2.0\testcode.py", line 18, in <module>
    g = f('x**2')
  File "C:\python\swampy-2.0\testcode.py", line 6, in _d
    return functools.update_wrapper(d(fn), fn)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
    setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A decorator takes a function as an argument and returns another "decorated" function.  You're passing a string and attempting to return a function which is really a function factory.  `functools.wraps` and `functools.update_wrapper` expect a function.  A function object would have a `__module__` attribute while instances of `str` don't have an `__module__` attribute.

Do you want to generate a function from the string "x**2"?

Your implementation of `decorator` is unnecessary.  Just use `functools.wraps`:

```
def f(fn):
    """Converts the string fn to a function and returns it."""
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def _f(fn):
        return eval(fn)
    return _f
```

However, you don't want a decorator in this case but a function factory.

```
def factory(exp):
    def f(**kwargs):
        return eval(exp, globals(), kwargs)
    f.__name__ = exp
    return f
```

Now you can use this like this:

```
>>> x_squared = factory("x**2")
>>> x_squared(x=7)
49
```

Warning: The Surgeon General Has Determined that `eval` is Dangerous to Your Health

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Yes, I'm well aware that eval should be used with extreme caution :)  In this case, though, I think I'm going to stick with it.

In this particular instance, its critical that I also store the exp in _f.__name___.  It doesn't seem like any of these solutions provide for that requirement.

Comment: In this instance, what _f() is actually doing is not really my main concern (I should have made that clear in my question).  I'm mainly concerned with updating the function wrapper using a decorator.